# Store multiple instances of same item in Django ManyToMany relationship

Tags: python, django, orm, django-models

I have a Django model representing a simple grocery list, as follows (truncated for brevity)

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)

class GroceryList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    meals = models.ManyToManyField(Meal)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)
```

This allows a `GroceryList` to contain both `Meal` objects, and `Ingredient` objects. (This way a list can group ingredients together when they're needed for a Meal.)

**The problem is**, I want a `GroceryList` to be able to contain the same `Meal` twice, or more. What's the most efficient solution?

I had considered wrapping the `Meal` class in an object ('`MealContainer`') that maintained both the underlying `Meal`, alongside a quantity, but that seems a little heavy-handed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps consider a [`through` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) with a `quantity` field.

Comment: Came here to suggest exactly this. You may also want to implement a custom count() method, which takes this into account...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the most efficient way, but you could break down your list of meals into daily menus. That's typically how my wife plans our grocery list.

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    MEAL_TYPE = (
        (u'B','Breakfast'),
        (u'2','Second Breakfast'),
        (u'E','Elevenses'),
        (u'L','Luncheon'),
        (u'A','Afternoon Tea'),
        (u'D','Dinner'),
        (u'S','Supper'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)
    meal_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=MEAL_TYPE)

class DailyMenu(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    meal = models.ManyToManyField(Meal)

class GroceryList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    meal_menus = models.ManyToManyField(DailyMenu)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)
```